# Visual Studio Shell 14 upgrade ruins command capturing in VSPackage

Tags: c#, envdte, vspackage, visual-studio-shell

I have a Visual Studio Shell 2013 application and I would like to upgrade to Shell 2015 and I faced with a problem related to command capturing. In the old version the <kbd>F1</kbd> command is captured and overwrite the default behaviour. (based on [How to capture Visual Studio commands in a VSPackage Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035240/how-to-capture-visual-studio-commands-in-a-vspackage-plugin))

This is the code from VSPackage that is working with the shell 13:

```
  m_objDTE = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));

  var F1HelpGuid = typeof(VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID).GUID.ToString("B");
  var F1HelpID = (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.F1Help;

  F1HelpEvent = m_objDTE.Events.CommandEvents[F1HelpGuid, F1HelpID];
  F1HelpEvent.BeforeExecute += CapturedF1HelpCommand;
```

After the update the <kbd>F1</kbd> command is not captured.

Do You have any idea why can it happened? Does the <kbd>F1</kbd> help Id changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to see my latest response to your post in the [VS Extensibility forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79c19456-5f12-4f0a-8b0e-b0f933ecc68c/visual-studio-shell-14-upgrade-ruins-captured-f1-functionality?forum=vsx)?

The reason the event never fires is because the Help commands are disabled via the stub applications' ApplicationCommands.vsct. You need to comment out the

entry to reenable the F1 command. Then, you should see your event handler being invoked.

Comment: Sorry Ed due to my late response, Thanks the research and the hep